# SwiftUI :Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, exc-bad-instruction

I am new in SwiftUI and I am currently developing my first big application.The program runs successfully in the simulator however the simulator screen is all white and I get the error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

in the AppDelegate(to which I have made no changes)
the app already consists of multiple files , however I can not find any problems in my code however many times I check it. What type of error should I be looking for?

Comment: "application.The program runs successfully in the simulator however the simulator screen is all white" You consider an all white screen "runs successfully"?

Comment: This tells nothing. Would you show code? Would you provide backtrace of crash (in debug console type `bt all` once crash happened)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of Swift code,

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

usually means you’ve hit a compiler trap, that is, an undefined instruction inserted into the code by the compiler because of a bug detected at runtime. The most common cause of these are:
failure to unwrap an optional —

1. This can be a forced unwrap (!) or an implicit unwrap (accessing an implicitly unwrapped optional that’s nil).
2. array out of bounds
3. a failed forced cast (as!), either because the value was a nil optional or because the value was of the wrong type

You can debug this issue by creating a exception breakpoint. As the name suggests, this stops the code execution before the execution of the line that throwed this exception.

To Create a exception breakpoint in Xcode, Go to BreakPoint navigator -> Click the + icon at the bottom left corner -> Select Exception Breakpoint.

More about breakpoints check this [link](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/xcode-breakpoints-tips/)